# C++ {fmt} library: How to leverage builtin format specification parsing for outputting custom type?

Tags: c++, fmt

This is related to using the [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) c++ library.

I have a templated rational type that contains a numerator and denominator that I am formatting by specializing `fmt::formatter` as described in the documentation. I would like to accept the same format specification that an integral type accepts without having to explicitly write the code to parse the specification.

Based on the documentation, I see that I can derive my specialization of `fmt::formatter` from `fmt::formatter<int>` and it will handle parsing of the specification which is great. In the documentation examples, the underlying format method of the formatter is then called to handle the output. In my case, however, I need to format two values separated by a /.

How can I leverage the underlying formatter for formatting both the numerator and denominator?

---

**UPDATE:**

The following formatter specialization does the basics and outputs numbers in the format `p/q` if `q` is not 1, or just `p` if `q` is 1, with the formatting spec applied to `p`, which is not exactly how I'd like it to work. I would like the specified width in the format string to be applied to the entire output not just the numerator, but I am unsure how to get a handle on that information.

```
template<rational::Rational T> struct fmt::formatter<T>
    : fmt::formatter<typename T::numerator_type> {
    using base_type = fmt::formatter<typename T::numerator_type>;
    template<class FormatContext>
    auto format(const T& r, FormatContext& ctx) {
        auto n = r.num();
        auto d = r.den();
        if (d == 1)
            return base_type::format(n, ctx);

        base_type::format(n, ctx);
        return format_to(ctx.out(), "/{}", d);
    }
};
```

Comment: What's stopping you from overriding the format method to simply call the inherited format method twice with different inputs and then concat them together? Can you please show the code you are having trouble with?

Comment: I updated the question with a code example and some additional detail. I am uncertain about how I am using the format and format_to methods, but the code seems to work as expected.

Comment: "*I would like the specified width in the format string to be applied to the entire output not just the numerator, but I am unsure how to get a handle on that information*" - Did you read the documentation? [Formatting User-Defined Types](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#formatting-user-defined-types)

Comment: Yes, that is one of the things I am uncertain about. It returns the same type as `ctx.out()`, but I am unsure how to combine the results for `format` and `format_to` to get the final return value. I am trying to read the `fmt` code, but it is still unclear.

Comment: And, of course, I have read the relevant documentation several times. I completely understand how I could write code to parse the format specification and use that information to output my type, but since the `fmt` library has obviously already implemented the code for parsing format specifications, probably much more rosbustly than I could hope to, I was hoping to be able to leverage that instead of writing my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the width to be applied to the entire output, you'll need to parse it yourself in the `formatter::parse` function and then delegate the rest to the element formatter if needed. In the `formatter::format` function you'll need to format into an intermediate buffer (e.g. `fmt::memory_buffer`) first and then copy the result into the output padded with fill characters. For example, the [chrono formatter](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/cbc7b8d5c1a0a88671fa1497d9e09197fde334f2/include/fmt/chrono.h#L2258-L2274) does exactly that. The extra copy can be omitted if the width is not specified.

Once formatting of ranges supports width you'll be able to do it in a simpler way by reusing a range formatter with `/` as a separator and empty delimiters. But right now it is not supported.